# c# event with multiple function overloads

Tags: c#, events, overloading

I am trying to make some events the someone can subscribe to, But i want to give the option to use different types of voids that can be used. See the following for clarification:

```
public event Action<float, float> MouseMove;
public event Action<Vector2> MouseMove;
public event Action MouseMove;
```

sending of the events

```
MouseMove(MouseX, MouseY);
MouseMove(new Vector2(MouseX, MouseY));
MouseMove();
```

So now in threory the user can subscribe in the following ways:

```
c.MouseMove += DoWithMouseMove;
```

And now this user has the ability to create the following types of functions depending on his needs like so:

```
static void DoWithMouseMove(float x, float y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x +"  "+ y);
}
```

or use the following pattern:

```
static void DoWithMouseMove()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mouse is moving");
}
```

But this isnt possible because i get the following error:

> already contains a definition for 'MouseMove'.
>   On the class that contains the events

How can i do this or is this not possible?

If something is unclear or needs further clarification let me know, so i can edit the question!

Comment: Have you looked at the `EventArgs` pattern that is typically used in .NET code?

Comment: Even if you could, now your publisher of events has to call clients in at least **3** different ways

Comment: You cannot have more than 1 variable with the same name regardless of whether it is an event or something else.

Comment: @Flydog57 My asumption was that he propably kept it simple for demonstration purposes. But there is at least a 25% chance he really did not know.

Comment: @Flydog57 I kept it simple for demonstration purposes, but i must admit i didnt fully understand EventArgs either..

Comment: Use a class derived form `EventArgs`. If some data is expensive to compute, then you might compute it on demand if it is not always needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is impossible.

Events are little more then a wrapper around a Delegate. They add a public add and remove function, while turning the backing variable Private.
And I do not know of a way to "mix" delegates in the same delegate variable.

Plus even if you could do that, how would you sensibly raise those events? You as the writer of this class are responsible to raise those events and fill all those Parameters. Ideally using a protected RaiseEvent() function.

It is also wierd why you think you need this. In your example, you would propably implement the first option. A event user that does not care for the values (`public event Action MouseMove;`) would just not retreive those values. And a user that needs a vector (`public event Action<Vector2> MouseMove;`) could just build one himself from those values.

Edit: I also second that you should follow the established Event pattern: (object sender, customEventArgsInstance e). Do not throw arguments just randomly into the signature, that makes it hard to proces your event.